# How to change resolution of first screen on startup?

Tags: boot, display, resolution

When I start my pc, the first screen I see, has a small resolution, but by the time I get to the login screen, the resolution is good. My video card is a GTX 680. It worked perfectly before, but not since I uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers. How do I change the resolution of the first screen, shown below?

[image: First screen]

Comment: Hi Joshua! I've merged your accounts. In the future, please stay logged in so you can comment on answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

That screen is displayed by the motherboard BIOS, it is probably not something you can change.

I would press <kbd>Del</kbd> and see what options (if any) are available.

---

According to some random stuff I tripped over whilst wandering the Intertubes:

> Gigabyte Mainboard includes the standard funtion of replacing the Fullscreen-Bootlogo with a custom picture by using the "Face Wizard" software included on the driver disc.

Maybe your mobo has this feature.

Comment: But my screen was perfect before until i deleted the drivers

Comment: Your video drivers aren't used in this stage of startup. Deleting them shouldn't directly effect this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Intel have this ITK (Integrator Tool Kit) thing that lets you configure more than you can see in the regular BIOS menu.
Try to see who's the manufacturer of your Motherboard through the BIOS, and then search for their software.

Comment: It's a custom built pc it has a gigabyte motherboard

Answer (score 0):

> When I start my pc, the first screen I see, has a small resolution,

Yes, this is normal. Most IBM compatibles desktop PC'seither boot in text mode our use a low resolution graphics mode which just about every monitor from the last few decades can handle. This is good.

> but by the time I get to the login screen, the resolution is good.

Your operating system will load drivers for various devices, including drives for your graphics card. That enables more than just the low resolution modes. Typically it will also remember your settings from the last time and use those. This is why it changes resolution **once the OS is active**, but not before it is loaded.

Given these two points I am convinced that your resulution never was any different in the past. However that does not mean that the image on the screen is not different.

A low resulution image on a higer resolution display can be treated in several ways, e.g.

1. The image can be drawn only in the top-left corner.
2. The image  can de draw centered in the screen with black bars around it.
3. or, **the image can be stretched**. That way it still fills the screen, even though it is at a lower resolution.

The last can be done both by the graphics can or via the electronics in your monitor. I suspect that you changed something here. Check these settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your LCD or LED Setting**

- Make sure Resolution or Monitor is set to (**full screen**) not on (**aspect ratio**).
- Turn of **DDC/CI** (**OFF**) in Monitor Setting.
- Set (**ACM**) to (**OFF**)
- Set **Wide Mode** to **FULL**